# mod_rewrite issue or maybe my server is the issue?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having a bit of a fit here. I'm wading into the vast pool of .htaccess in order to rewrite my URLs to be SEO friendly.

I have been researching this all day. I take code snippets from  various tutorials and SO posts, yet I get no results and most of the time, no errors.

I have a cPanel dedicated server running Apache 2.0. I called my host, LunarPages, and verified that mod_rewrite was installed and it is, and apparently is working fine.

where I'd like to start is changing the name of `index.php` to `/home/` as in `http://www,website.com/home/` making the trailing slash optional as well as home being case insensitive.

Literally, everything I try is doing nothing, it's as though the request is being ignored completely.

I'm writing the .htaccess file in Notepad on my PC and uploading it with FileZilla with the transfer type set to ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I'd like to start is changing the name of `index.php` to `/home/` as in `http://www,website.com/home/` making the trailing slash optional as well as home being case insensitive.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?home/?$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Note that if you have any relative links (like to scripts or CSS) in `index.php` and you go to `http://www,website.com/home/`, the relative links will have `/home` as a base (instead of `/`). And you'll either need to make those links absolute or add a URI base to the page header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. So there's got to be something on my server end because the code you provided did not change the URL to `http://www.website.com/home/` it still ends in `/index.php` What should I be looking for in the server end?

Comment: @mileaminute The code above makes it so when you type **`http://www,website.com/home/`** in your browser's URL address bar, and the request for `/home/` arrives at the webserver, and then the rule above internally rewrites it to `/index.php`. This doesn't do anything about changing what's on the client, this is a server-side thing. If you want your URL to look like `http://www.website.com/home/` in your browser's address bar, make sure you are creating links that look like `http://www.website.com/home/` and **not** `http://www.website.com/index.php`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, yes, I see that works! Your answers have been concise and well-explained. I can't thank you enough!